# Planar Embedding (Planar Face Traversal) Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, graph, planar-graph

I have a graph `G`. The graph is a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).

I wish to find all the faces of the graph. I understand that [constructing a planar embedding is the way to find the faces ( or regions, or cycles)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/for-a-planar-graph-find-the-algorithm-that-constructs-a-cycle-basis-with-each-e), such that all the edges must be shared by at most 2 faces.

Is there a readily made implementation of planar embedding algorithm in C#? Either commercial or open source is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I found that [Planar Face Traversal](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html) function in Boost library suits my needs.

One can then wrap the function in plain C manner and call it from C# via PInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this C# project says it was inspired by the Boost library, and says it supports:

- Checks if a given undirected graph is planar or not
- Computes planar embedding if a given graph is planar
- Computes faces of a given planar embedding

It appears to use Boyer-Myrvold Planarity Testing:

- Checks that if a graph is one big cycle, it is planar and there are exactly two faces in the embedding
- Checks that if a random graph has more than 3n - 6 vertices, it is not planar

https://github.com/OndrejNepozitek/GraphPlanarityTesting